# Is the doctor in or on?

Tags: prepositions

How to say when you want to say that someone is available in his office, like *The Doctor is in his seat* or *The Doctor is on his seat*?

Comment: 'The Doctor is on his seat' sounds as if you have to wait, because he is on the toilet. I would just say 'The Doctor is available'.

Answer (score 2):

Native English speakers usually sit *on* benches, stools, counters, or the ground, but *in* any kind of chair. This is not, however, how you indicate that a professional person is available, especially if they have regular office hours. Instead, the person is simply *in*.

[image]

Comment: I think one can sit on a chair. It would not be a comfortable chair (maybe an office or waiting-room chair), one you would not be surrounded by with comfortable arms and the like, but *on* is not out of place.

Comment: Victorian ladies were certainly trained to sit on, not in chairs because it would have been unladylike to use the back of the chair for support. One can still maintain that whaleboned rigidity or discomfort by sitting _on_ a chair as one might a backless bench, but it's the posture, not the furniture, that would determine the preposition for me.